How should I manage multiple versions of a library in a Python project
I am working on a Python project, which has to support multiple versions of the same package.
For each new version, some of our wrapper classes change, and others remain unchanged from the previous version.
Currently, I have three versions, but I am expecting the fourth version next year, and I would like to support all of them.
To illustrate my problem, I have created this minimal example:
 .
├──  pyproject.toml
└──  src
    └──  version_example
        ├──  __init__.py
        ├──  bar
        │   ├──  __init__.py
        │   ├──  bar_1.py
        │   └──  bar_2.py
        ├──  baz
        │   ├──  __init__.py
        │   ├──  baz_1.py
        │   ├──  baz_2.py
        │   └──  baz_3.py
        ├──  foo
        │   ├──  __init__.py
        │   └──  foo.py
        └──  main.py

Here is my pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry]
name = "version_example"
version = "0.0.1"
description = ""
authors = []
packages = [{ include = "version_example", from = "src" }]

And here is main.py:
import os

from version_example.foo.foo import Foo

if int(os.environ["TARGET_VERSION"]) == 1:
    from version_example.bar.bar_1 import Bar
else:
    from version_example.bar.bar_2 import Bar

if int(os.environ["TARGET_VERSION"]) == 1:
    from version_example.baz.baz_1 import Baz
elif int(os.environ["TARGET_VERSION"]) == 2:
    from version_example.baz.baz_2 import Baz
else:
    from version_example.baz.baz_3 import Baz

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo()
    bar = Bar()
    bar()
    baz = Baz()
    baz()

Each object is a callable, and when called prints out its name, e.g.:
# version_example.bar.bar_2
class Bar:
    def __call__(self):
        print("Bar version 2")

This approach does not scale with new versions.
What changes do I have to make, so that the calling code does not know of the versioning?
E.g. what would I have to do to achieve something like this?
# main.py
from version_pecific.foo import Foo
from version_pecific.bar import Bar
from version_pecific.baz import Baz

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo()
    bar = Bar()
    bar()
    baz = Baz()
    baz()

One option, would be to break the module into three different modules:
 .
├──  poetry.lock
├──  pyproject.toml
├──  src
│   └──  version_example
│       ├──  __init__.py
│       └──  main.py
└──  versions
    ├──  version_1
    │   └──  version_pecific
    │       ├──  __init__.py
    │       ├──  bar.py
    │       ├──  baz.py
    │       └──  foo.py
    ├──  version_2
    │   └──  version_pecific
    │       ├──  __init__.py
    │       ├──  bar.py
    │       ├──  baz.py
    │       └──  foo.py
    └──  version_3
        └──  version_pecific
            ├──  __init__.py
            ├──  bar.py
            ├──  baz.py
            └──  foo.py

We can then add the corresponding version module to the PYTHONPATH, e.g. export PYTHONPATH=./versions/version_3:$PYTHONPATH.
The drawback of this approach however, is that I have duplicate Python files, e.g. bar.py would be duplicated in version_2, and version_3, and foo.py would be duplicated in all the version packages.
Another approach, would be to move the TARGET_VERSION-check to the __init__.py files.
As an example, src/version_example/bar/__init__.py would have:
import os

if int(os.environ["TARGET_VERSION"]) == 1:
    from version_example.bar.bar_1 import Bar
else:
    from version_example.bar.bar_2 import Bar

and src/version_example/bar/__init__.py would have:
import os

if int(os.environ["TARGET_VERSION"]) == 1:
    from version_example.baz.baz_1 import Baz
elif int(os.environ["TARGET_VERSION"]) == 2:
    from version_example.baz.baz_2 import Baz
else:
    from version_example.baz.baz_3 import Baz

Here, we do not have to copy any code, and the calling code does not have to know of the version, however we have added one level of indirection, so that when I am reading through the code, and following the imports, I have to be aware of the value of TARGET_VERSION.
Therefore, I wonder, can I use poetry, or any other Python build-tool, to install the version specific code as packages, and for each package, declare a dependency on the lower version, so that each package can decide, whether to import a class from the previous version, or override this with a new version?
I feel like this should be a rather general problem for a package that has to support multiple versions of the same library, yet I have not been able to find a satisfactory solution to this.
Any hints or keywords to look up would be much appreciated!

importlib.util.find_spec("version_example.baz.baz_1")

I tend to approach such problems in a more narrow way: presumably, your wrappers aren't completely changed each time a library version is bumped, only a few things change from version to version. In the spirit of DRY (don't repeat yourself), I'd try not to copy the whole wrapper code, but to put the version specific logic deep, exactly where your code needs to know which version is there.

Well, you have version = "0.0.1" so that would be a red flag for anyone trying to install between four different versions

@joanis thanks, that's actually where I started from, when I only had 2 versions. That way, I had to import different modules from the library depending on the target version. By splitting each wrapper class into 2, I could hide away the version-specific imports from the target library, and that's when I also got the idea of splitting it into modules and use the PYTHONPATH to select the correct module. When I then had to add support for the 3rd version, which had some classes in common with the 2nd, and some new classes, I realized that that did not work well with more than 2 versions.
